# How to throw the exception and catch it in the Node.js?

Tags: c++, node.js, exception

I am writing an ADD-ON using C/C++ in Node.js. For some reason, I need to throw the exception in C/C++ Add-on side, and to catch the exception in the JavaScript side.

JavaScript side:

```
try {

var conn = addon.get(); 

} catch(e) {
  console.log("catching....................");
}
```

C/C++ code:

```
if (args.Length() <= 1 && !args[1]->IsFunction()) {
    ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Arguments 1 expect a function!")));
}
```

The actual behavior is:
For WIN:
A dialog pop-ups and shows:

---

### Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

> Assertion failed!
>
> Program: ...verMananger\src\wrapper\build\Release\nodedb2.node File:
>   c:\users\ibm_admin.node-gyp\0.10.1...\node_ob..._wrap.h Line: 60

Expression: !handle.IsEmpty()

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

### (Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)

### Abort   Retry   Ignore

For Linux:

> node: /root/.node-gyp/0.10.9/src/node_object_wrap.h:60: static T*
>   node::ObjectWrap::Unwrap(v8::Handle) [with T =
>   NodeDB2Connection]: Assertion `!handle.IsEmpty()' failed.

How to throw the exception and catch it in the Node.js?  Did everybody meet the same problem as I met?

Comment: `args.Length() <= 1 && !args[1]->IsFunction()` should be `args.Length() <= 1 || !args[1]->IsFunction()`, or something similar, I guess. This may already fix your stuff. As to the nodejs portion: I have no idea about nodejs development.

Comment: Thanks for you comments.

I am confusing :
ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Arguments 1 expect a function!")));

I threw the exception in C/C++ side, why JavaScript side can not catch it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good, except you are not returning anything. Throwing an exception up to node is not the same as a regular C++ exception. All you need to do is add the follwoing line after your call and you should be good:

```
return scope.Close(Undefined());
```

So everything would look like this:

```
if (args.Length() <= 1 && !args[1]->IsFunction()) {
  ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Arguments 1 expect a function!")));
  return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```